# How to sum duplicate values while all of my other columns are included in my report?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

**MY QUESTION DESCRIPTION:**

This is my table in SQL SERVER: (The contained data is previously entered.)

```
ID   CodeColumn  NameColumn QNT UnitCost Description
1       121        lute     3    100000    blah
3       122       Leather   10   50000     blah
```

I have a program in C# which has reletive textboxes for all of these colums.

this is my addgoods store procedure:

```
CREATE procedure AddGoods

@QCode nvarchar(50),
@QName nvarchar(50),
@QQNT int,
@QUnitCost int,
@QDR int,
@QDesc nvarchar(250)

as
Insert Into GoodsTable1(CodeColumn,NameColumn,QTYColumn,UnitCostColumn,DiscountRateColumn,DescriptionColumn) values (@QCode,@QName,@QQNT,@QUnitCost,@QDR,@QDesc)
return
```

this is my desired report store procedure:(which yells at me)

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() Over (ORDER BY namecolumn) AS RowNumberColumn,
 CodeColumn,
 NameColumn,
 SUM(QNTColumn) AS QNT,
 UnitCostColumn,
 DiscountRateColumn,
 SUM(UnitCostColumn) AS Total,
 DescriptionColumn
FROM GoodsTable1
GROUP BY NameColumn
```

When I get input from user, every time that the same code or name is entered, I want  the value of the `quantity column` to be the sum of the reletive values of the comodities within the input.
Also I want the values of `UnitCost Column` to be summed and showed as `TotalColumn`.

for example:
(as I said these datas are previously entered)

```
1       121        lute     3    100000    blah
3       122       Leather   10   50000     blah
```

when I get new input from user eg. :

```
121        lute     5    100000    information
```

I want to be able to report this from my data base:

```
121        lute     8    100000    *(blah gets deleted)* information
```

I tried this in my query to avoid the error:

```
select
    NameColumn,
    SUM(QTYColumn),
    SUM(UnitCostColumn)
    FROM GoodsTable1
GROUP BY NameColumn
```

it works but I need other columns in as well.

Comment: Why tag c#?. . .

Comment: sorry i edited it.

Comment: Can you show us the `AddGoods` store procedure?

Comment: Okay I will copy it right now.

Comment: You can get other columns by Listing them in `GROUP BY` clause... For example `select CodeColumn,
    NameColumn,
    SUM(QTYColumn),
    SUM(UnitCostColumn)
    FROM GoodsTable1
GROUP BY NameColumn, CodeColumn`. But be careful they must be unique values, or you have wrong results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is pretty unclear and contains some discrepancies. Let's try to clean it up:

Your column is called QNT in sample data and QTY in query. I suspect this is just a mistake. Same for other columns. Let's assume your table looks like in the sample below:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
    ID int identity,
    CodeColumn varchar(8),
    NameColumn nvarchar(20),
    QtyColumn int,
    UnitCostColumn decimal(15,2),
    DescriptionColumn nvarchar(MAX),
    DiscountRateColumn decimal(15,2) DEFAULT (0.0)
)

INSERT @table(CodeColumn, NameColumn, QtyColumn, UnitCostColumn, DescriptionColumn) VALUES
(121, 'lute', 3, 100000, 'blah'),
(122, 'Leather', 10, 50000, 'blah'),
(121, 'lute', 5, 100000, 'blah')
```

Then, you can calculate running total as follows:

```
SELECT *,
    SUM(QtyColumn) OVER (PARTITION BY CodeColumn ORDER BY ID) RunningQty,
    SUM(UnitCostColumn) OVER (PARTITION BY CodeColumn ORDER BY ID) RunningCost
FROM @table
```

Result:

```
ID   CodeColumn NameColumn   QtyColumn   UnitCostColumn  DescriptionColumn  DiscountRateColumn   RunningQty  RunningCost
---- ---------- ------------ ----------- --------------- ------------------ -------------------- ----------- ------------
1    121        lute         3           100000.00       blah               0.00                 3           100000.00
3    121        lute         5           100000.00       blah               0.00                 8           200000.00
2    122        Leather      10          50000.00        blah               0.00                 10          50000.00
```

I also expect, that you are trying to preserve only last record from each group. Above query could be rewritten as:

```
SELECT */*select all columns you need*/ FROM (
    SELECT *,
        SUM(QtyColumn) OVER (PARTITION BY CodeColumn ORDER BY ID) RunningQty,
        SUM(UnitCostColumn) OVER (PARTITION BY CodeColumn ORDER BY ID) RunningCost,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CodeColumn ORDER BY ID DESC) LastRank
    FROM @table
) T WHERE T.LastRank=1
```

Result:

```
ID  CodeColumn NameColumn  QtyColumn   UnitCostColumn  DescriptionColumn  DiscountRateColumn  RunningQty  RunningCost  LastRank
--- ---------- ----------- ----------- --------------- ------------------ ------------------- ----------- ------------ ---------
3   121        lute        5           100000.00       blah               0.00                8           200000.00    1
2   122        Leather     10          50000.00        blah               0.00                10          50000.00     1
```

To provide more compact and efficient solution, more information is needed.

Comment: I'm trying to help too but OP has a problem on the table structure. I suggested to see more for Normal Form of Relational Databases because this table is not well structured. Also you can't aggregated results for the same item differing only from the description. Logically the description should be the same, because it is the same item. So it is better to create a relation between a new table who is used to store only the items details and this table left only with `CodeColumn`, `Quantity` and `UnitsCost`.

Comment: @Pawel Dyl - wow thank you for your time it really helped me I was waiting for and expecting something like this. your idea is much better than mine. I just cant understand the "T" part on the last line of your last query.`T WHERE T.LastRank=1`.  please let me spend more time to study your answer and ask more questions IF i needed to. thank you...

Comment: T is just an alias of subquery (subselect). In this example it can be anything unless **T**.LastRank matches.

Comment: Hi again would u please explain `T WHERE T.LastRank=1` part for me a little more? I anlyzed alot but still cant Understand it :(. whats the `T`. why u have a `T` after `where`. why you said `T dot lastRank` I tought we couldnt say something dot something else in SQL(i thought it was available only in c#)

Comment: does it mean, name the subquery `T` and select blah where `T` something?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the query like this

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() Over (ORDER BY namecolumn) AS RowNumberColumn,
CodeColumn,
NameColumn,
SUM(QTYColumn) AS QTY,
UnitCostColumn,
DiscountRateColumn,
SUM(UnitCostColumn) AS Total,
DescriptionColumn
FROM GoodsTable1
GROUP BY CodeColumn, NameColumn, UnitCostColumn, DiscountRateColumn, DescriptionColumn
```

You can add extra fields that you want in both `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses but be sure to have unique values because you will get wrong results.

Comment: I want to have rownumber column and description coulmn as well... does this work?

Comment: You can add `Description` too as I added the `CodeColumn`... Rownumber express a counter of the row? You can do it in c# code... Or ask me to find something if you want only in SQL.

Comment: Could you suggest me a better way to fulfill this project need?

Comment: What is rownumber? Did you mean the ID if the row or just an incremental number in front of a table... starting from 1 ang going to the total rows?

Comment: you know I edited the question and added my report store procedure. I created row number like I mentioned in the report store procedure. but how can I have row number like that in the group by clause? is it possible?

Comment: I got your answer it works for me (except the row number). but as you said this code is not reliable. couldnt you suggest me a better way?

Comment: I updated the query... this wont give any error and does what you want.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I need the sum of both 'QuantityColumn' and the 'UnitCostColumn' AS TOTAL COST. how can I implement this with that code?

Comment: They are there... expressed as `QTY` and `Total` in your final query results.

Comment: This is what can you do with the way you have set up the table. You should learn more about Relational database normal form (1NF 2NF 3NF). From the search I found [this](https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php) that might help.

Comment: yup ur right. thank you for your help. I appriciate your support and time. I will definitely study the link you sent me cause I need it.

Comment: I actually wanted to ask another question, does it have any weeknesses to have a row number column like this: row_number() Over (ORDER BY `id`)?

Comment: You're welcome! If you got the solution, don't forget to mark it as answered.

Comment: For other questions you can create posts. Long comment threads won't help anyone. However it doesn't have to do with weakness. It's how you want to order the rows.

Comment: I got it. Yes I will mark it thank u for remining me. during this delay i was actually tesing the code. the only problem is that I have to enter the same excat descripion for the goods in order for program to be able to add duplicate rows together otherwise the program doesnt do it. I want the description column not to be considered for adding duplicate columns but I want it to be shown in report section. how is it possible any ideas?

Comment: You can't with this structure... Think this: If you have an item with id and name, nad insert the same item (id and name)... you have only one row. You can't have multiple rows for the description.... The only way to fix this is to get the only one description, which you can achieve by using `MAX(DescriptionColumn)` in SELECT clause and removing it from GROUP BY clause. In this case it will take the last one when you order alphabetically. (For the first one use MIN ;) ).